# Show pdf from string presenting bytes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pdf, blob

I have a component which contains a button onClick it show the documnent the user clicked on. The problem is the pdf document is of type strings representing bytes, the pdf is shown is always empty. Can someone help in that?

```
export function DocumentsView() {
  .....
  const { data: documentPdf } = useGetDocument(requiredDocumentId);
  const handlePreview = async (documentId: string) => {
    setRequiredDocumentId(documentId);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const openPdfInNewWindow = async () => {
      if (requiredDocumentId && documentPdf?.data) {
        try {
          // Concatenate array of strings into a single string
          const byteCharacters = documentPdf.data.join("");

          // Convert string bytes to Uint8Array
          const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteCharacters.length);
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
          for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteArray[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
          }

          // Create Blob from Uint8Array
          const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: "application/pdf" });

          // Create URL for Blob
          const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

          // Open PDF in a new window
          window.open(url, "_blank");
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error opening PDF:", error);
        }
      }
    };

    openPdfInNewWindow();
  }, [requiredDocumentId, documentPdf]);

  return (
        <Documents data={processDocuments!} handlePreview={handlePreview} />
    </Box>
  );
}
export default SaleView;
```